# Puppet prefix function does not seem to prefix the result

Tags: puppet

I am trying to provision a splunk alert for a cluster of Kafkas. I have this code, and the hiera data "kafka_hosts" is a map with hostnames as keys.

```
$kafka_hosts = keys(hiera('kafka_hosts'))
$splunk_host_expresssions = prefix($kafka_hosts,'host=')
$splunk_hosts_expression = join($splunk_host_expresssions,' OR ')
```

`$splunk_hosts_expression` comes out as just host names separated by OR.
the prefix `host=` does not turn up.

The result I want is:

```
host=a.example.org OR host=b.example.org OR host=c.example.org
```

Puppet version is 2.7

Comment: I fail to reproduce your error with Puppet `2.7.23` and stdlib `4.3.2`. I ran `puppet apply -e '$kafka_hosts = [ "a.example.org", "b.example.org", "c.example.org" ] $splunk_host_expresssions = prefix($kafka_hosts,"host=") $splunk_hosts_expression = join($splunk_host_expresssions," OR ") notify { $splunk_hosts_expression: }'`

Comment: Have you tried this ? 
`$str="host"      $splunk_host_expresssions ="${str}=${kafka_hosts}"`